# How to create a struct in C++

Tags: c++, struct

Suppose I have a struct called Node as follows:

```
struct foo
{
   foo *next;
   int aNum;
};
```

How do I create an "instance" of this in C++ (in a main method for instance)? I've looked around and it seems as if I would just do

```
foo name;
```

But it seems to me as if I should have to allocate space first.  Can someone explain (a long explanation is not necessary)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you define your instance like this, it is an object of *automatic storage duration*. That means that the compiler generates code for you that takes care of allocating and freeing the memory for that object.

This method has limitations. The lifetime of an object created in this way is always bound to the lifetime of a surrounding function or an owning object. Also, if the object is a local variable inside a function, it will usually be allocated on the stack, which is usually quite limited in size.

Comment: Are you sure its always automatic storage duration? Consider global variables.

Comment: They still have automatic storage duration - bound to the lifetime of the program.

Comment: So would this cause a memory leak because C++ does not have any garbage collection?

Comment: @Nosrettap: No it would not - like I said, the compiler will generate code that handles the cleanup - hence the name *automatic storage duration*.

Comment: Global objects have static storage duration. Unlike objects with automatic storage duration they will also be destructed when calling `exit`.

Comment: @celtschk: Thanks for the correction, I was not aware of that.

Answer (score 3):

`foo name;` is the way to do it. This will allocate storage for it on the stack, which is called static allocation (except when the variable is global, which means it will be allocated in the program executable file itself).

If you want to allocate it dynamically (you often don't need to do that in C++), use `std::unique_ptr<foo> name = new foo;` or `std::shared_ptr<foo> name = new foo;`. Also see [`std::unique_ptr` reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr) and [`std::shared_ptr` reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr).

Comment: This is true if and only if the declaration is placed inside a function. It is not true for global variables, because they're not placed on the stack. Right?

Comment: Global variables live throughout the entire program lifetime (with some exceptions). You are right, yes.

Comment: `foo* name = new foo;` // you don't need to put `()` there... Don't forget to `delete name;` when you finish with it.

Comment: Under normal circumstances, i.e. in absence of specifiers like `static`, the allocation on the stack is *not* a static allocation. Objects living on the stack have automatic storage duration.